# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/xtext/service/AbstractGenericModule

Tags: guice, shared, xtext, xtend

after more than a day of searching i am really stuck in resolving the problem of a eclipse xtext RCP.

launching the .product results in the error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/xtext/service/AbstractGenericModule
```

the result is, that non of the DSL-Editors show up. instead a blank Tab is created in the RCP.
except a comprehensive stack trace, the eclipse IDE is not very precise in it's expression of the problem.

so far i am using:

- eclipse Neon (201606...)
- Xtext 2.11
- Maven 3.5.x

Product configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?pde version="3.5"?>

<product name="XXXXXXXXXX" uid="com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxxx.product" id="com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxxx.product.product" application="org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" version="1.0.0.qualifier" useFeatures="false" includeLaunchers="true">

   <configIni use="default">
   </configIni>

   <launcherArgs>
      <programArgs>-consoleLog
      </programArgs>
      <vmArgs>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
      </vmArgs>
      <vmArgsMac>-XstartOnFirstThread -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
      </vmArgsMac>
   </launcherArgs>

   <windowImages/>

   <launcher name="mss-testbench">
      <solaris/>
      <win useIco="false">
         <bmp/>
      </win>
   </launcher>

   <vm>
      <windows include="true">org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8</windows>
   </vm>


<plugins>
      <plugin id="ch.qos.logback.classic"/>
      <plugin id="ch.qos.logback.core"/>
...


<configurations>
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.runtime" autoStart="true" startLevel="4" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.common" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.ds" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.event" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator" autoStart="true" startLevel="1" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.osgi" autoStart="true" startLevel="-1" />
      <plugin id="org.eclipse.update.configurator" autoStart="true" startLevel="3" />
      <property name="org.eclipse.update.reconcile" value="false" />
   </configurations>

   <preferencesInfo>
      <targetfile overwrite="false"/>
   </preferencesInfo>

   <cssInfo>
   </cssInfo>

</product>
```

please let me know if you need more details.
many thanks

Comment: it seems that though validating the plugin-dependencies eclipse didn't complained about the missing plugin:
`org.eclipse.fx.core.guice`
after including this plugin and pressing "add required plugins" in the run configuration the error was gone.
... let's see how it goes with the Maven Headless Build

Comment: `AbstractGenericModule` is in `org.eclipse.xtext` are you sure it is part of your product?

Comment: well it may be a coincidence that the Error disappeared in the RCP launched from eclipse. When build with maven the error still persists. There are discussions here mentioning to solve it with a new
`ExecutableExtensionFactory`: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/825658/ 
another solution sees the Start-Level of the plugins as a reason for this Error: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1073549/

so far i added all xtext & xtend modules except source modules

Comment: Sure you are in the same usecase?

Comment: so far it seemed a Framework mismatch between Xtext versions. one is creating the <LanguageName>GenericModule through Mwe2-Generation - the other doesn't ...
Finally ensuring that XText 2.11 is used in any case the classes were created and the error disappeared.

Comment: I have come acroess the same error, how did you ensure xtext 2.11 was used? By adding the version in the manifest?

Comment: Well you can define it in the target definition. create another simple project in the workspace and put a: new->other->target definition in it. the best thing is in my experience to create the target from scratch with online software site. it's also mandatory if you want to build your project later with maven/tycho, so better you start now. You'll find all repositories on the eclipse.org site. use google to find the links to the p2 repo's. for xtext. e.g. there is a subfolder named 2.11 within the according xtext repository.